# Populate PHP Array Values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Here is my code:
I am getting data from mysql query and getting array of values. But i am not able to populate in javasript. could you please any one help me out...

PHP Code:

```
   $parishFamilyInfo = $parishFamilyInfoBO->sendBirthdayGreeting($personalInfoSearchDO,  $parishFamilyInfoSearchDO);
    foreach ($parishFamilyInfo as $parishFamily){
       if(!empty($parishFamily->email)){
               print_r($parishFamily);
     }
   }
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var t = $('#people').bootstrapTransfer(
    {'target_id': 'multi-select-input',
         'height': '15em',
         'hilite_selection': true});
        t.populate([   /*here i need to populate php array value*/
            {   
                value:"<?php print_r($parishFamily->email);?>", 
                content:"<?php print_r($parishFamily->name);?>"
            },
        ]);


        //t.set_values(["2", "4"]);
        //console.log(t.get_values());

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

**`print_r` is *only* for debugging. It's not for anything else.** Let me quote the [documentation](http://php.net/print_r):

> `print_r` — Prints **human-readable** information about a variable

As stated above, it is a debugging function that's used to print the contents of a variable in a more readable manner. It just returns a string  — JavaScript does not and will not understand this format.

Use JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) instead. It is is a light-weight data interchange format that is very popular nowadays. You can use the built-in function [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) to create the JSON representation of your PHP array and then transfer it to JavaScript. JSON being language independent and based on the JavaScript scripting language, your JavaScript code will now be able to parse the array:

```
t.populate([
    {   
        value: <?php echo json_encode($parishFamily->email); ?>, 
        content: <?php echo json_encode($parishFamily->name); ?>
    },
]);
```